# Substrate: How to validate the originator of unsigned extrinsics?

Tags: substrate

I need to be able to identify the source of an unsigned extrinsic for spam prevention purposes. Assume there is a set of known authorities from whom I am willing to accept an unsigned extrinsic. I want to check that the sender of the unsigned extrinsic is a member of this authority set (and that they are who they say they are).

From what I can tell there are a couple of different approaches and I would like to better understand the differences between each and the trade-offs involved.

1. Add a signature as a call parameter and define [`ValidateUnsigned`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.ValidateUnsigned.html).

   This approach is used in the [`ImOnline`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/src/pallet_im_online/lib.rs.html#684-734) pallet. Roughly speaking:

   ```rust
   decl_module!(
       // ...

       fn my_unsigned_call(_origin, 
           args: MyArgs<T>, 
           authority: T::Authority, 
           signature: T::Signature) {
           // Handle the call
           todo!()
       }
   )

   impl<T: Trait> frame_support::unsigned::ValidateUnsigned for Module<T> {
       // ...

       fn validate_unsigned(
           _source: TransactionSource,
           call: &Self::Call,
       ) -> TransactionValidity {
           if let Call::my_unsigned_call(args, authority, signature) = call {
               // Check the sender is in the approved authority set and verify sig
               todo!();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement [`SignedExtension`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html) for some metadata associated with the pallet trait. This is touched upon in the docs and seems to be implemented in the [`TransactionPayment`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/22441aa4bc40200cbd98503e6f44769dd39f7031/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs) pallet. Implementation would be something like this:

   ```rust
   struct SenderInfo<T> {
       authority: T::Authority,
       signature: T::Signature,
   }

   impl<T: Config + Send + Sync> SignedExtension for SenderInfo<T>
   where
       <T as frame_system::Config>::Call: IsSubType<Call<T>>,
   {
       // ... 

       fn validate_unsigned(
           call: &Self::Call,
           info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
           len: usize
       ) -> TransactionValidity {
           // validate self.authority and self.signature

       }
   }
   ```

   This `SignedExtension` then needs to be aggregated into the [`SignedExtra`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/node_runtime/type.SignedExtra.html) of the runtime. (Right?)

I am tending towards using the second option since it seems cleaner: it doesn't require me to pollute my method signatures with extra information that is not even used in the method call. But would this mean that *any* transaction submitted to the runtime, signed or unsigned, would need to add this customised `SignedExtra`?

Are there any other considerations I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a very similar thing.

I was able to do so with your approach 1.
Basically I do check two things there:

1. If payload was signed properly - When you think about it, this will tell you only about the user, but it doesn't check if a user is your authority user.
2. I do check if this account is on my authorities list

My working example is available here https://github.com/korzewski/jackblock/blob/master/pallets/jackblock/src/lib.rs#L401

Although, this is not perfect because I need to keep a second list of Authorities and add them manually.

Currently I'm trying to refactor it, so my authorities accounts are the same as my validators (Aura pallet). Still looking for a solution so maybe you know how to solve it? Basically how to reuse Aura pallet in my own pallet

Comment: Thanks. Coming back to this a bit late...
I think you're right, the first approach is the only one that works, however since the signature is included in the transaction hash, transactions from different accounts will not be de-duplicated in the mempool, which is a bit sad.

Edit: Have a look at this if you are still trying to solve your problem wrt. pallet re-use / composition: https://substrate.dev/recipes/pallet-coupling.html

Comment: Also, just to expand on why 2. doesn't work: The data from the `SignedExtension` is not available when performing the `validate_unsigned` check, so it reverts to being the same as the first case, that is, you need to include the account ID and signature in the call signature.